# Using articles with brand names

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, definite-article

One example:

> One student has reported that Safari web browser ..

The brand `Safari` is mentioned for the first time in the text.

Another case:

> We store the data using Oracle database

Shall I use the article `the` before `Safari` and `Oracle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the article in both cases. The reason is that it relates to "web browser" and "database" respectively.

You can think of Safari and Oracle as adjectival nouns, e.g

> One student has reported that the *new* web browser ...
>
> One student has reported that the *Safari* web browser ...
>
> _
>
> We store the data using the *most reliable* database
>
> We store the data using the *Oracle* database